# AltBeacon: BeaconConsumer in Service Not Working

Tags: android, service

in this thread
[Beacons not detected in Android service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29148007/beacons-not-detected-in-android-service)
but when i put the code in manifest

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.ubiquitous.beaconone.tablet"
android:versionCode="3"
android:versionName="2.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:taskAffinity="">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activities.ScanningActivity"/>

    <service
        android:name="org.altbeacon.beacon.service.BeaconService"
       android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:isolatedProcess="false"></service>
    <service
        android:name="org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconIntentProcessor"
        android:enabled="true"></service>

</application>
```

I GOT AN ERROR:

Error:(48, 13) Attribute service#org.altbeacon.beacon.service.BeaconService@exported value=(true) from AndroidManifest.xml:48:13

Error:(48, 13) Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute service#org.altbeacon.beacon.service.BeaconService@exported value=(true) from AndroidManifest.xml:48:13
>       is also present at org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2.1.4:27:13 value=(false)
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:exported"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:45:9 to override

Comment: show your full manifest file

Comment: Question has been updated, ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove

```
 android:exported="true"
```

from service tag of **org.altbeacon.beacon.service.BeaconService**

Answer (score 1):

When using the [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library), you generally do not want to put its service declarations in your manifest because the library itself contains its own AndroidManifest.xml file and uses a process called manifest merging (automatic when using Android Studio) to merge the entries from the library into your app's manifest.

This process will copy the manifest entries shown here: https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/blob/master/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

In the code shown in the question, conflicting entries have been put into the app's manifest, so merging fails.  This is the meaning of the error message.

The precise source of the conflict is the attribute `android:exported="true"`.  The value of this attribute has been changed to false in the latest version of the library.

You can fix this several ways.  Choose only **one** of the following:

1. Remove the two service entries from your manifest.   The merger will add proper entries automatically.
2. Change `android:exported="true"` to `android:exported="false"`
3. Add `tools:replace="android:exported"` right after `android:exported="true"`
4. Turn off manifest merging and enter all of the entries yourself.  You will also need to copy over the `StartupBroadcastReceiver` entry if you want auto launching.

See a related discussion here: http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/alternate-configuration.html